# Realtek wifi adapter installed but not working

Tags: wireless, realtek

I bought a wifi dongle, and tried to get it to work in ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
It came with a disk, realtek drivers.  They didnt work, so I got some that do work, for some. I installed them, and now the system recognizes the driver, but when I blacklist the built-in wifi, the Realtek driver didn't connect to the internet. The message was that there was no wifi adapter.

Then I tried to install the driver for windows 10. This PC is an HP Pavilion windows 10 machine which has Ubuntu, and the Linux boot manager installed.  Needless to say, the windows driver on the realtek drivers disk, didn't work, but one I found on the Internet works.

I've gone through several extensive debug sessions on this Web site but they seem to peter out with no indication as to wether a solution was found or everyone gave up.

What do you suggest?

---

I reran some informational commands that were in my terminal history.

### The output follows...

```
bobp040653@bobp040653-400-314:~$  sudo dkms status
[sudo] password for bobp040653: 
rtl8812au, 4.2.2, 5.0.0-37-generic, x86_64: installed
bobp040653@bobp040653-400-314:~$ lsusb
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0bda:c811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 03f0:0d4a Hewlett-Packard 
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0158 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB 2.0 multicard reader
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0461:4e23 Primax Electronics, Ltd 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
bobp040653@bobp040653-400-314:~$ lshw -C network
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 07
       serial: a0:d3:c1:31:96:4a
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:24 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:d0804000-d0804fff memory:d0800000-d0803fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlp4s0
       version: 01
       serial: b8:ee:65:ef:e3:dd
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=5.0.0-37-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.6 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:33 memory:fea00000-fea7ffff memory:fea80000-fea8ffff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
bobp040653@bobp040653-400-314:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 07
       serial: a0:d3:c1:31:96:4a
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:24 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:d0804000-d0804fff memory:d0800000-d0803fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlp4s0
       version: 01
       serial: b8:ee:65:ef:e3:dd
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=5.0.0-37-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.6 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:33 memory:fea00000-fea7ffff memory:fea80000-fea8ffff
bobp040653@bobp040653-400-314:~$ 
bobp040653@bobp040653-400-314:~$ lsmod | grep 8812
bobp040653@bobp040653-400-314:~$ 
bobp040653@bobp040653-400-314:~$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
bobp040653@bobp040653-400-314:~$
```

---

Here's my terminal history without any output.
As follows...

````
  197  cd ~/Downloads
  198  ls
  199  cd Linux
  200  dir
  201  ls -l 
  202  cd RTL8811CU_WiFi_linux
  203  dir
  204  cd ..
  205  dir
  206  ls -l
  207  cd Lin*
  208  dir
  209  ls -l
  210  cd RTL8812BU_WiFi_linux
  211  ls -l
  212  cd ..
  213  dir 
  214  ls -l
  215  cd RTL8811CU_WiFi_linux
  216  ls -l
  217  unzip *zip
  218  dir
  219  cd *linux
  220  ls -l
  221  install.sh
  222  sudo ./install.sh
  223  ls -l
  224  chmod a+x *.sh
  225  sudo ./install.sh 
  226  ls -ltr
  227  cd ..
  228  ls -l
  229  cd *BU*
  230  ls -l
  231  unzip *zip
  232  ls -l
  233  cd *BU*44
  234  ls -l
  235  chmod a+x install.sh
  236  sudo install.sh
  237  sudo ./install.sh
  238  sudo apt update
  239  sudo apt install git
  240  git clone https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au.git
  241  sudo cp -r rtl8812au  /usr/src/rtl8812au-4.2.2
  242  sudo dkms add -m rtl8812au -v 4.2.2
  243  apt get dkms
  244  man apt
  245  apt install dkms
  246  sudo apt install dkms
  247  sudo dkms add -m rtl8812au -v 4.2.2
  248  sudo dkms build -m rtl8812au -v 4.2.2
  249  sudo dkms install -m rtl8812au -v 4.2.2
  250  ```sh
  251  sudo dkms status
  252  ls RTL*
  253  dir RTL*
  254  dir
  255  rtl88*
  256  cd rtl*
  257  dir
  258  vi os_dep
  259  ls -l
  260  vi README.md
  261  ifconfig
  262  sudo apt install net-tools
  263  ifconfig
  264  sudo -i
  265  lsmod | grep 8812 
  266  lsmod
  267  rfkill list all
  268  sudo -i
  269  cd Down*
  270  ls -l
  271  ls linux
  272  cd Linux
  273  ls -l
  274  lsmod | grep 8812
  275  rfkill list all
  276  sudo modprobe rtl8812au
  277  sudo modprobe 8812au
  278  sudo vi /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
  279  sudo dkms status
  280  lsusb
  281  lshw -C network
  282  sudo lshw -C network
  283  cd /downloads
  284  cd ~downloads
  285  ~~~~
  286  h
  287  history
bobp040653@bobp040653-400-314:~$
````

Comment: be aware that if the on-board and usb device use the same driver module, disabling it will disable for both devices

Comment: The on-board is Atheros.